# Sections in VSCode is is greyed out?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code, statusbar, vscode-extensions

[image]

Color theme that I use is dark+, but suddenly status bar, panel and editor has been greyed out. I can't seems to change it back. To make it more clear I changed its theme to Light+ (Only to post the question so that I can explain it better and make the problem more prominent). In the posted image editor should be in light color kind of white or so. but it is still black and also the status bar is still grey while it should be blue.
Also the problem is not with the language because I tried c++ also and It was still same in colors.
Can you help me to fix it?
Solutions I tried:

1. Reinstalling the editor: Ofcourse it didn't work. It reverted back to previous setting.
2. Deleting all the extensions also didn't work.

[image]

This is how it is on light mode.
Please help it is really ruining my coding experience.

Note: I am not asking to fix the color code but that is probably not the problem here or else status bar wouldn't have been grey out.

Comment: Have you tried switching to a built-in theme? Maybe the theme you are using is corrupt?

Comment: Yes,  I tried that too.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Same issue with the `Atom theme` and working with Python.